# ggplot2: two different multiple GLM poisson model regression ajusted and confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, glm, poisson

I've like to creat a plot in ggplot2 that combine two different multiple GLM poisson model regression ajusted and confidence interval (IC 95%).

For this I make:

```
#Artificial data set
Consumption <- c(501, 502, 503, 504, 26, 27, 55, 56, 68, 69, 72, 93)
Gender <- gl(n = 2, k = 6, length = 2*6, labels = c("Male", "Female"), ordered = FALSE)
Income <- c(5010, 5020, 5030, 5040, 260, 270, 550, 560, 680, 690, 720, 930)
df3 <- data.frame(Consumption, Gender, Income)
df3

# GLM Regression 
fm1 <- glm(Consumption~Gender+Income, data=df3, family=poisson)
summary(fm1)

# ANOVA
anova(fm1,test="Chi")

#Genders are different than I ajusted one model for male and another for Female

#Male model
df4<-df3[df3$Gender=="Male",]
fm2 <- glm(Consumption~Income, data=df4, family=poisson)
summary(fm2)

#Female model
df5<-df3[df3$Gender=="Female",]
fm3 <- glm(Consumption~Income, data=df5, family=poisson)
summary(fm3)

#Create preditions amd confidence interval
Predictions <- c(predict(fm2, type="link", se.fit = TRUE),
                 predict(fm3, type="link", se.fit = TRUE))
df3_combined <- cbind(df3, Predictions)
df3_combined$UCL<-df3_combined$fit + 1.96*df3_combined$se.fit
df3_combined$LCL<-df3_combined$fit - 1.96*df3_combined$se.fit
df3_combined<-df3_combined[,-(5:9)]
df3_combined<-as.data.frame(df3_combined)


#Plot
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
df3_combined %>%
  gather(type, value, Consumption) %>%
  ggplot(mapping=aes(x=Income, y=value, color = Gender, lty = type)) + 
  geom_point() +  
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Income, y=exp(fit))) +
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(ymin = exp(LCL), ymax = exp(UCL)), stat="identity") 
#
```

But my output plot below have a problem and doesn't work very well.

[image: n]

This line for Consumption was wrong. Any member, could help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on your code, the data frame passed to `ggplot()` has only one value for line type, namely `type = "Consumption"`. I'm not sure what line you are referring to when you claim the line for Consumption was wrong. Can you include a sketch of what you expect the output to be?

Comment: my good output is remove of this vertical type Consuption line in y. Male adn female lines are OK, only one line for each model.

Comment: Then remove `lty = type` from your `aes(...)` mappings.

Comment: Doesn't work, when:                                                                                      
#Plot
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
df3_combined %>%
  gather(type, value, Consumption) %>%
  ggplot(mapping=aes(x=Income, y=value, color = Gender)) + 
  geom_point() +  
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Income, y=exp(fit))) +
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(ymin = exp(LCL), ymax = exp(UCL)), stat="identity") 
#